# Returning TextField Input using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, textfield

EDITTED - still getting same error

I'm trying to create a function that will get a word chosen by the user, verify that it is all characters, and then return it. But I get the error

```
"incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
 unexpected return value
 Unnecessary return statement"
```

I don't understand how to change it to make it work better.

```
 String newWordScene(Stage primaryStage)
{
    Text prompText = new Text("Word to guess: ");
    TextField wordToGuess = new TextField();
    Button submitButton = new Button();

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.add(prompText, 0, 0);
    grid.add(wordToGuess, 0, 1);
    grid.add(submitButton, 0, 2);

    Scene newWordScene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(newWordScene);
    primaryStage.show();

            submitButton.setOnAction(e->
    {
        if(verify(wordToGuess.getText()))
            return wordToGuess.getText();
    });
}
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error. When you use a return statement in a lambda, you have to use braces like `e -> { return wordToGuess.getText(); }`

Comment: surround with curly braces or simply `wordToGuess.getText()`

Comment: What Button class are you using. I cannot find one with a setOnAction() method.

Comment: I'm using the package javafx.scene.control.Button

Answer (score 0):

When using a lambda with setOnAction() you cannot return a value.

Comment: What should I do to get that value then?

Comment: @SamanthaBlansett What do you want to do with the text value?

Comment: I'm using it for a hangman type game where one user chooses a word and the next player has to guess it.

Comment: @SamanthaBlansett Then you need to store the word somehow. Most likely in a field.